# Jquery tab inside tab activate by subtab index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

```
<div id="mystudenttab">
    <ul>
        <li><a id="parenttab-0" href="#ParentTab-0">ParentTab1</a> </li>
        <li><a id="parenttab-1" href="#link1Tab-1">link1Tab</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="ParentTab-0">
        <table>
            <tr><td>link1Tab</td></tr>
            <tr><td>link2Tab</td></tr>
            <tr><td>link3Tab</td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div id="link1Tab-1">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#subtab1-273">Student Info</a></li>
            <li><a href="#subtab2-273">Call Info</a></li>
            <li><a href="#subtab3-273">Mail Box</a></li>
            <li><a href="#subtab4-273">Case History</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div id="subtab1-273">This is subtab1</div>
        <div id="subtab2-273">This is subtab2</div>
        <div id="subtab3-273">This is subtab3</div>
        <div id="subtab4-273">This is subtab4</div>
    </div>       
</div>
```

Hi, this is my tab structure. Basically this is tab inside tab groups. I have to focus inside tab group `(link1Tab-1)` by **tab name or index or id**.

I am using activate option and it is activating first tab every time.

After activate parent tab, i am calling `$("[href='#subtab1-273']").click();` to activate child tab. Here how i will pass child tab id for activate.

Answer (score 0):

look into jquery .trigger.  https://api.jquery.com/trigger/

```
$("[href='#subtab1-273']").trigger('click', { childID: "someID"});
```